# Attempting to return an array of objects but for loop freezing inside function

Tags: arrays, callback, return

var uri =['https://open.spotify.com/album/51vRvV83RdWGP9FpzGe4SQ','https://open.spotify.com/user/diplomaddecent/playlist/6AvLNaeJ7qeF1Ur1kNoiXT','https://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX4dyzvuaRJ0n']

```
function seperateUri(uri,callback){

    for (var i=0;i<uri.length;i++)
    {
       function callback(result){
                                 return {
                                        type: result[2],
                                        id: result[3]
                                        }
                                }

     var parse_uri = /[a-z]+:\/{0,2}(open.spotify.com)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)$/i ;
     result = parse_uri.exec (uri [i] ) ;
     return this [i] = callback(result) ;
     }
} 



seperateUri(uri);
```

Comment: `return this [i] = callback(result) ;` seems a little weird. what are you trying to do here? given your example, it should break out of the for loop and leave the seperateUri function after examining only the first element in the passed in uri array

Comment: of course, the return is breaking the loop, any ideas on a way to do this?

Comment: Im trying to return an object for each array element which has been reg ex seperated so i can get the keys that relate to each array

Comment: well it looks like you're trying to build up an object with the result from `callback(result);`. if you create an empty object, `var results = {}`, and then do `results[i]=callback(result);` that may work. try it out, and just leave out the `return` keyword from your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = {} ;
function seperateUri(uri,callback){

    for (var i=0;i<uri.length;i++)
    {
       function callback(result){
                             return {
                                    type: result[2],
                                    id: result[3]
                                    }
                            }

     var parse_uri = /[a-z]+:\/{0,2}(open.spotify.com)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)$/i ;
     result = parse_uri.exec (uri [i] ) ;
     results[i] = callback(result) ;
     }
} 



seperateUri(uri); //populates the results object
```

`results` object will hold little child `result` objects. you can access the individual result objects and do with them as you please, but the return keyword was breaking your loop prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

var uri = ['https://open.spotify.com/album/51vRvV83RdWGP9FpzGe4SQ', 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3CsiXF2gHbhWGW38GKnZln', 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2zINKv6Jg7zVf6Od61itzs']

function seperateUri(uri, callback) {

```
for (var i = 0; i < uri.length; i++) {


    var parse_uri = /[a-z]+:\/{0,2}(open.spotify.com)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)$/i;
    result = parse_uri.exec(uri[i]);
    this[i] = callback(result, i);

    function callback(result, i) {


        this[i] = {
            type: result[2],
            id: result[3]
        }

        return this[i]

    }


}
return this
```

}

console.log(seperateUri(uri)[1].id)